# How to pass radio button IsChecked property as command parameter

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

Right now I have a xaml page in MAUI .Net with the following radio button

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1"
                     Value="Player1"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                     BorderWidth="1"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     IsChecked= "True"
                     >
            
            <RadioButton.Content>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                    <Binding Path="Name1"/>
                    <Binding Path="Player1.Score"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RadioButton.Content>
            <RadioButton.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                        EventName="CheckedChanged"
                        Command="{Binding ChangeCurrentPlayerCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}"
                    />
            </RadioButton.Behaviors>
        </RadioButton>
```

And I the command is the following method on my ViewModel.

```
[RelayCommand]
        void ChangeCurrentPlayer()
        {

            if (CurrentPlayer == Player1)
            {
                CurrentPlayer = Player2;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentPlayer = Player1;
            }

        }
```

I want to pass the IsChecked property of the button as a parameter to the command, but the application throws an exception of type:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'
```

Is there any way I can do this?
The reason I need to pass that state as an argument is to get around the fact that whenever a radio button is clicked the command is fired twice in a row, making it useless, unless I have a way to know which button is currently calling it.

Comment: May I ask how you bind your CurrentPlayer? Have you tried set the ```CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference radioButton1}, Path=IsChecked}"```

Comment: And in viewmodel change the RelayCommand: ```[RelayCommand]void ChangeCurrentPlayer(bool s)```

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/radiobutton. And focus on RadioButtonGroups. This what you are doing is wrong for more than one reason.

Comment: @H.A.H. How is it wrong exactly? Those two buttons are supposed to be on the same group.

Comment: @GuilhermeTakata exactly: because the annotated method does not accept any arguments, because checked changed will trigger twice, and because checking visual elements state is not the right way for MVVM architecture. Read the document I told you to read. This what you do is not good at all.

Comment: @GuilhermeTakata May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behaviours don't have unique visual tree parents so we cannot use RelativeSource binding on it. Please refer to this issue: [Relativesource bindings and behaviors](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8584#issuecomment-558153141).

As a workaround, you could try the following method.

in xaml, change the Binding for CommandParameter:

```
<StackLayout>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1"
         ...
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         IsChecked= "True"
         >
        ...
        <RadioButton.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="CheckedChanged"
            Command="{Binding ChangeCurrentPlayerCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference radioButton1}, Path=IsChecked}"
        />
        </RadioButton.Behaviors>
    </RadioButton>
```

This binds the CommandParameter to the IsChecked Property of this radiobutton1.

And in viewModel, pass the correct parameter (IsChecked is bool type), like this:

```
[RelayCommand]
void ChangeCurrentPlayer(bool isChecked)
{
    var a = isChecked;   
    Console.WriteLine("123");
}
```

Hope it works.